# Loud cracking sound on brand new Seagate Exos 16tb HDDs

Tags: hard-drive, nas

Just bought new QNAP NAS and brand new Seagate Exos 16TB X18 HDDs. Everybody who are using them, does they make similar sound as mine?

They make so loud clicking and scratching noise that it doesn't sound healthy. Other HDDs normally make just quiet humming from spinning.

These make scratching noise which is audible on whole room. Second half of the video is when nas is on idle, then they spin every 5 secs.

Here is the video: https://youtu.be/v-ry9N5pkDk

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the video that's entirely normal. The actuators make that noise when they're moving, and that noise increases with more heads/capacity, heavier actuators and faster access speed.

Some drives have acoustic management (AAC) where you can trade access speed for noise, but not these server-grade disks.

If that's too noisy you'd need absorbing mounts, an insulated case or slower/smaller disks.

Comment: Weird if thats normal sound but that can be the case. No other hard drives sound like that. Specially when they spin every 5 seconds its very noticeable scrathcing sound.

Little too noisy for being on apartment. I can try put some velcro adhesive beetween drives and nas but dont think its going to help much.